# Interpolation Error Problem.

Tags: solution-verification, numerical-methods, numerical-optimization

**Problem**
Let $p_{n-1}$ be a polynomial of degree $\leq(n-1)$ that interpolates the function $f(x)=e^{x}$ at any set of $n$ nodes in the interval $[-1,1]$. Prove that the error obeys this inequality on $[-1.1]$,
$$p_{n-1}(x)-f(x)\leq \frac{2^{n}e}{n!} \forall x[-1,1] $$

**Solution**: From interpolation error formula for $n$ nodes, we have
$$p_{n-1}(x)-f(x)\leq \frac{(x-x_{1})(x-x_{2})(x-x_{3})......(x-x_{n})}{n!}f^{n}(c)$$
Where $c\in[-1,1]$.
Here, $f(x)=e^{x}$. Therefore, $|f^{n}(c)|\leq e^{1}$.
And, because the interval is $[-1,1]$. The maximum difference froma a specified point can be $2$.
Thus ,
$$p_{n-1}(x)-f(x)\leq \frac{2^{n}e}{n!} \forall x[-1,1] $$

Is my solution correct? And can anyone give a more articulate solution similar to mine. As my solution looks way too casual.

Comment: Your solution is fine. Maybe just stating explicitly that $|x-x_i| \leq 2$ for all $i$ and for all $x \in [-1,1]$.

Comment: And use the absolute value in all inequalities. Else you prove only one half of the claim, and probably use invalid inequality transformations.